# Skip List probabiility

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, probability

Assume that you currently have *n* elements to construct a skip-list data structure. What is the probability that the height *h* of the skip-list is larger than *4 log n*?

What should I be looking at to answer this question? I'm confused how Skip-Lists can be related to probability. I'm mainly looking for direction on how to answer.

Comment: Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how to tackle this problem, where do I start? What should I be using?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, but 1/2 (flip a coin) is best probability. Some people speaks that 1/3 gives better result, but my observations do not is classic 1/2 is best.

Answer (score 0):

> Where do I start?

Well, lets assume that you have all of those N elements and that you can create an *optimal* skip-list.

Now think of what can affect the height of the skip-list.

---

Now that I think of it, I'm not even sure that it makes sense to talk about probabilities for this problem.  Certainly, you would need some kind of probability function for ... whatever is variable in the problem.  If you treat `N` as the only variable, then this isn't strictly a probability problem at all.

This makes me think that *maybe* you haven't given us the complete problem specification.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't able to find any reference to probability in relation to Skip Lists, but now I have some direction. Thanks again =)

Comment: What's random is that each element has an independently chosen height with [geometric distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution).

Comment: @DavidEisenstat - That it only true given certain assumptions about the way that the skip-list is constructed.